# Files download in Chrome, but not in Safari, but console.log(response) and Network tab shows the file being sent from the server

Tags: download, safari

So I'm starting to do cross-browser optimization for my React/Django application. Files download fine in Chrome, but when it comes to Safari, it looks like it downloads the file from the server, but doesn't actually download the file to the default download location (Downloads).

I can `console.log(response)` showing the server responded with the file, and can also see in the Safari Network tab that it was downloaded so kind of stumped. (Well, at least I think that it is what it is saying... really not used to Safari dev tools). Not sure what I could post code-wise to assist with this.

This is what I am seeing:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is related to the library I am using for downloading in React:

https://github.com/kennethjiang/js-file-download/issues/24